# How we can revoke an old device certificate when a new certificate installed on the same device?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I have an AWS IoT implementation which will do Just In Time Registration (JITR) such as activating the device certificate using Lambda function. Steps are followed as mentioned in (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/just-in-time-registration-of-device-certificates-on-aws-iot/).

Now when a new device certificate is issued in device and when it do the JITR I would like to revoke the old certificate in JITR Lambda function. Here each device certificate will be signed with same CA certificate. I will get new certificate ID and CA certificate ID from MQTT topic.

How we can revoke an old device certificate when a new certificate installed on the same device?

Answer (score 0):

```
 delete --certificate-id id_of_certificate
```

This line should remove the certificate. You need to de-attach any policies before deleting it.